# How to pass a reference to a function that takes references as argument

Tags: c, pointers

I cannot figure out how to make my program work. The program ask user to input a number and print them out. I use the linked list to store my values. But cannot get it working, need help
. I used a structure.h file to define my structure

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H_
#define STRUCTURE_H_

struct intNode
{
    int value;
    struct intNode *next;
};

#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structure.h"
#define commandLength 6
#define initSize 100

void insert(struct intNode *head, struct intNode *current);
void print(struct intNode *head);

int main()
{
    char command[commandLength];
    struct intNode *head = NULL;
    struct intNode *current = NULL;

    printf("Enter a command from the following list of commands:\n\n"
            "insert - to add a number to the list;\n"
            "print  - to print out the list;\n"
            "exit   - to terminate the program;\n\n"
            "Enter your command:\n");

    while (strcmp(command, "exit") != 0)
    {
        scanf( "%s",command);

        if(strcmp(command,"insert") == 0)
        {insert(head, current);}
        else if(strcmp(command, "print") == 0)
        {print(head);}
        else if(strcmp(command, "exit") == 0)
        {printf("\nThe program has been terminated.");}
        else
        {printf("Error: unknown request '%s'\n", command);}
    }//end of while
}//end of main

void insert(struct intNode *head, struct intNode *current)
{
    struct intNode *node;
    node = (struct intNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct intNode));
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&node->value);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        if(head->next == NULL)
        {
            head->next = node;
            current = node;
        }else{
            printf("%d ",current->value);
            current->next = node;
            current = node;
        }
    }
}//end of insert

void print(struct intNode *head)
{
    struct intNode *temp;
    temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}//end of print
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insert(head, current);` function you are passing the parameters but they are also output parameters. So you need to pass address of them and then change their value which will be reflected in `main()`. So change that call to

```
insert(&head, &current)
```

And update your function as

```
void insert(struct intNode **head, struct intNode **current)
{
    struct intNode *node;
    node = (struct intNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct intNode));
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&node->value);
    //--v note * here and other places
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        if((*head)->next == NULL)
        {
            (*head)->next = node;
            *current = node;
        }else{
            printf("%d ",(*current)->value);
            (*current)->next = node;
            (*current) = node;
        }
    }
}//end of insert
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created two versions of your code. One annotated with the [most of] the bugs and a cleaned up and working version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].

When you set `head` in insert, it didn't set this in `main`, only in `insert`. I solved this using the "dummy" node as list header approach.

---

Here's the annotated version:

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H_
#define STRUCTURE_H_

struct intNode {
    int value;
    struct intNode *next;
};

#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structure.h"
#define commandLength 6
#define initSize 100

void insert(struct intNode *head, struct intNode *current);
void print(struct intNode *head);

int
main()
{
    char command[commandLength];
    struct intNode *head = NULL;
    struct intNode *current = NULL;

    printf("Enter a command from the following list of commands:\n\n" "insert - to add a number to the list;\n" "print  - to print out the list;\n" "exit   - to terminate the program;\n\n" "Enter your command:\n");

    // NOTE/BUG: on the first time through the loop, command is invalid, so do
    // this:
#if 1
    command[0] = 0;
#endif
    while (strcmp(command, "exit") != 0) {
        scanf("%s", command);

        // NOTE/BUG: passing current serves no purpose
        if (strcmp(command, "insert") == 0) {
            insert(head, current);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "print") == 0) {
            print(head);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("\nThe program has been terminated.");
        }
        else {
            printf("Error: unknown request '%s'\n", command);
        }
    }                                   // end of while
}                                       // end of main

void
insert(struct intNode *head, struct intNode *current)
{
    struct intNode *node;

    node = (struct intNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct intNode));
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &node->value);

    // NOTE/BUG: when head is set here, it only modifies it within _this_
    // function and does _not_ update it in main
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
    }

    // NOTE: this is closer to the insertion you want to do
    else {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            head->next = node;
            current = node;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d ", current->value);
            current->next = node;
            current = node;
        }
    }
}                                       // end of insert

void
print(struct intNode *head)
{
    struct intNode *temp;

    temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}                                       // end of print
```

---

Here's the cleaned up and working version. I renamed `head` to `list` to be more descriptive of its new role.

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H_
#define STRUCTURE_H_

struct intNode {
    int value;
    struct intNode *next;
};

#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "structure.h"

#define commandLength 6
#define initSize 100

void insert(struct intNode *list);
void print(struct intNode *list);

int
main()
{
    char command[commandLength];
    struct intNode list;

    list.next = NULL;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command from the following list of commands:\n\n" "insert - to add a number to the list;\n" "print  - to print out the list;\n" "exit   - to terminate the program;\n\n" "Enter your command:\n");

        scanf("%s", command);

        if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("\nThe program has been terminated.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "insert") == 0) {
            insert(&list);
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "print") == 0) {
            print(&list);
            continue;
        }

        printf("Error: unknown request '%s'\n", command);
    }
}

void
insert(struct intNode *list)
{
    struct intNode *current;
    struct intNode *prev;
    struct intNode *node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(struct intNode));
    node->next = NULL;

    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &node->value);

    // find the end of the list
    prev = NULL;
    for (current = list->next;  current != NULL;  current = current->next)
        prev = current;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = node;
    else
        list->next = node;
}

void
print(struct intNode *list)
{
    struct intNode *temp;

    for (temp = list->next;  temp != NULL;  temp = temp->next)
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
    printf("\n");
}
```